# typeahead.js in a form with ember?

Tags: ember.js, typeahead.js

has anyone had success using typeahead.js in a form with ember?  I have been attempting to use ember-aupac-typeahead.  The typeahead shows the right values when I start typing, but when I submit the form, the value is not passed along with the rest of the form.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

component.js : `console.log(this.get('country'));`

template.hbs :
`{{aupac-typeahead action=(action (mut country))
      class='form-control'
      source=countrySource
      placeholder='Search for a country'}}`

There is [a twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2ff6a2e9f8ec250afd389a3c6c9f86d4?openFiles=twiddle.json%2C) using ember-aupac-typeahead. It is working as expected.

If you give a twiddle for your example, I can look it.